# bash script & gpg : trap decryption failed

Tags: bash, gnupg

I have a bash script that runs in the crontab. Its performs a GPG decryption of files.
I would like to intercept the error :

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID XXXXXXX
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
```

Here is my script :

```
#!/bin/bash
DECRYPT_DIR="/my_folder/"
THE_KEY="MY_KEY"
(
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T") : Start"
    for f in `ls ${DECRYPT_DIR}*.gpg`
    do
        filename="${f##*/}"
        filenameWithoutExtension="${filename%.*}"
        echo ${THE_KEY} | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --output /my_folder/decrypted_files/$filenameWithoutExtension --decrypt $f
        trap "mv $f /my_folder/decrypted_files/ERREURS/$filename; continue;" ERR
        mv $f /my_folder/ARCHIVES/$filename
    done
    echo "$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %T") : End"
) >& /my_folder/logs/gpgsh.log
```

It does move my file to `ARCHIVES`folder, but does not trap the decryption failure

Comment: Aside; you mean  `for f in "${DECRYPT_DIR}"*.gpg` -- see also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and [useless use of `ls`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Any clue about the "error"?

Comment: I would expect `gpg || exit` to do what you want, more or less, but I don't know if it suits your reality, as it will exit on any error, not just decryption error.  If there is a specific exit code for this particular error, you could obviously use that to improve on the basic idea.

Comment: Something like `(echo ${THE_KEY} | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --batch --output /my_folder/decrypted_files/$filenameWithoutExtension --decrypt $f) || (mv $f /my_folder/decrypted_files/ERREURS/$filename; continue;)`

Comment: Yeah, or refactor so that `mv` receives the destination as a variable which is reset to the default on each iteration, then redirected to the error directory if decryption fails.

Comment: @tripleee I don't believe gpg exits with 1 upon unsuccessful decryption